# Why didn't Dinah's name carry any attachment or prophetic meaning in Genesis 30:21?

Tags: genesis, jacob, israel

When Leah gave birth to her sons all their names carried an attachment or prophetic meaning

KJV Genesis 29 : 33 - 34

> And she conceived again, and bare a son; and said, Because the Lord hath heard that I was hated, he hath therefore given me this son also: and she called his name Simeon ***hearing***. 34 And she conceived again, and bare a son; and said, Now this time will my husband be joined unto me, because I have borne him three sons: therefore was his name called Levi ***joined***.

Also Rachel when she gave birth to her sons all their names carried an attachment or prophetic meaning

KJV Genesis 30 : 24

> and she called his name Joseph ***adding***; and said, The Lord shall add to me another son.

KJV Genesis 35 : 18

> And it came to pass, as her soul was in departing, (for she died,) that she called his name Benoni ***the son of my sorrow***: but his father called him Benjamin the son of the right hand.

Finally when Leah gives birth to her last born daughter she is just named plainly Dinah without any attachment or prophetic meaning to her name.

KJV Genesis 30 : 21

> And afterward she bare a daughter, and ***called her name Dinah***.

Did Leah feel she had achieved her goal of giving Jacob sons that there was no need to continue battling with her sister or it was some cultural influence that only boys should have attachments so as to shape their destinations.

Why didn't Dinah's name carry an attachment or prophetic meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The OP's assumption is that the name "Dinah" did not carry semantic and prophetic meaning.  The fact that it is not recorded does not mean that it lacked any significance.  Note that "Dinah" is a feminine form of the name "Dan" given to one of Jacob's other children.

Indeed, the name דִּינָה (Dinah) means, "Judged", or "justice" (BDB) which appears to have had some significance for the following reasons:

- Dinah and the appalling incident with the sons of Hamor resulted in calamitous judgement on that town - all the men were killed, Gen 34.
- Gill observes this (in commenting on Gen 3):21:

> **and called her name Dinah**; which signifies "judgment": perhaps she may have some reference to the first son of Bilhah, Rachel's handmaid,
> whom she called Dan, a name of the same signification; intimating as
> if it was a clear case that judgment went on her side; and that by the
> number of children she had, it was plain God had determined in her
> favour.